# Grid 3*3 with tableLayout

Tags: android, grid, tablelayout

I want a 3*3 grid with an ImageButton centered in each cell
I've done the code below

```
TableLayout tl=new TableLayout(this);
int intNbRows=3;
int intNbCols=3;
for (int i = 0 ; i < intNbRows;i++)
{
   TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);
   tr.setMinimumHeight(hauteur/intNbRows);//TODO : a voir 
   tr.setMinimumWidth(largeur/intNbCols); //TODO : a voir
   tr.setId(100+i);

   for (int j = 0 ; j < intNbCols;j++)
   {
      int numImage=((i*intNbCols)+j+1);
      final ImageButton myButton=new ImageButton(this);
      Drawable d=Drawable.createFromPath("/sdcard/b" + numImage  + ".png");
      myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
      myButton.setId(200+numImage);
      myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
      myButton.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
      myButton.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      tr.addView(myButton);
   }
   tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(largeur,hauteur/intNbRows));
   tl.addView(tr);
}
tl.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));           
this.setContentView(tl);
```

With this code, rows have the good height, but not width, and ImageButtons are not centered in cells....

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i need to put tablerows in linearlayout, and that works very well :)